# NUXT - asyncData and vue Actions error handling

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am on the route `http://mywebsite.com/[category that doesn't exist]` which (per the code below) throws an error. However, I can't seem to get to the catch block in asyncData.

```
async asyncData({ params, store }) {
  try { 
    await store.dispatch('categories/GET_CATEGORIES')
    await store.dispatch('products/GET_products', params.category)
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e) // doesn't console log anything
  }
}
```

Vuex action:

```
async GET_PRODUCTS({commit}, category) {
  try {
    let url
    if (!category) {
      url = 'some url'
    } else {
      url = 'some other url'
    }

    const response = await this.$axios.$get(url)

    if (!response.length) throw new Error()
    
    commit('some mutation', response.data)
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

When I throw the error, shouldn't it also call the catch block in asyncData? The reason why I want to do that is because I want to use the router to navigate to the home page if there is an error in the action.

I have found very little documentation about routing right inside Vuex (its not recommended?). However, asyncData has the `context` object which includes `router`.

Comment: I personally wouldn't consider that bad practice especially since you're catching it elsewhere. If you're concerned about it, you could still rethrow the error from your action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your action is already catching errors and swallowing them.

To allow the caller to handle the error, you could rethrow the error within your action:

```js
async GET_PRODUCTS({commit}, category) {
  try {
    //...
    const response = await this.$axios.$get(url)

  } catch(e) {
    // do something with `e` here...

    // then rethrow error
    throw e
  }
}
```